# Android "Urban Airship" - GCM - No active device tokens found

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

Ok I have recently upgraded the app from C2DM to GCM. For some reason I keep getting - 'No active device tokens found for alias' intermittently. I observed it happens when you leave the phone for some time or restart the phone. When i connect the adb I can see "com.zeebox.android.caa:com.urbanairship.push.process" in the process list.

Also, Is there any limit on no. of messages a device can receive?

Any help or pointers will be useful. Thanks

Comment: Ask the question with sample code on urban airship forum. Without knowing how the lib work, it's hard to say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a bug with UrbanAirship, you should bring it up with them. Also you don't explain what you did when you "upgraded" to GCM. If UA is still using C2DM then you can't just switch to GCM, there are changes that need to be made on the server side (which UrbanAirship controls in this case)

Comment: Yes, We have successfully made the server side changes,Main issue is - we are receiving UA(GCM) intermittently (sometimes we dont receive anything).

Answer (score 1):

U need to implement the GCM instead of Arnoid Urban ship.You are receiving the invalid token because of the change of policies of android.You can implement GCM with the help of the following link.Its the best tutorial i have ever found related to GCM. 
       http://androidmyway.wordpress.com/tag/android-gcm/